# Как просклонять "два человека"?

Tags: склонение

Как просклонять "два человека"?

два человека
двух человек
двум человекам
двух человек
двумя человеками
о двух человеках

Правильно ли?

Answer (score 1):

Дал сначала неверный ответ, вот исправленный.

Как отметила V.V., вы просклоняли правильно.

Есть ещё один нюанс, о котором говорится в [вопросе № 281621](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=281621) на Грамоте:

> Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать: "я познакомился с двумя человеками" или "я познакомился с двумя людьми"? (по следам передачи "Правила жизни" по "Культуре")
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Правильно: *с двумя человеками.* Употребление слова люди возможно при наличии *определения:* *с двумя **взрослыми** людьми.*

Answer (score 1):

Правильно. [Цитата](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=298427) с Грамота.ру:

> Форма "человек" употребляется с числительными.
>
> В сочетании с числ. пять, шесть (и далее) слово человек во всех падежах выступает в формах мн. ч., образованных от основы человек-, а не от супплетивной основы форм мн. ч. лю|д'|-: человек, человекам, человеками, о человеках (пять человек, с семью человеками).
>
> В сочетании с числ. два, оба, три, четыре перечисленные словоформы мн. ч. выступают во всех падежных формах, кроме формы им. п. (не было и двух человек, речь идет о трех человеках).
>
> При сочетании с формой им. п. этих числительных выступает словоформа род. п. ед. ч. (два человека, три человека, оба человека).
>
> При наличии определения в сочетаниях с числ. пять, шесть (и далее) во всех падежах и с числ. два, три, четыре в косв. пад. может употребляться слово люди: пять незнакомых человек и пять незнакомых людей, не было и трех взрослых человек и не было и трех взрослых людей.